# Successive conditional sum in R

Tags: r, nearest-neighbor

I m trying to code conditional sums within a data frame. I tried using the "sum" function together with the "which" function but cannot make it work. Here is a toy example:

The matrix named "distance" includes the distances from a given point N to 3 other points for 2 observations.
For the first observation, N1 is the nearest neighbor of N, the second nearest neighbor is N2, the third is N3.
Each point belongs to a class (A or B), which changes at each observation and this information is recorded in a matrix named "classes"

```
dist1 <- c(0.2,0.3,0.9)
dist2 <- c(0.1,0.6,0.9)
distance <- rbind(dist1,dist2)
colnames(distance) <- c("N1.dist","N2.dist","N3.dist")
rownames (distance) <- c("obs1","obs2")
classes.observation1 <- c("A","B","A")
classes.observation2 <- c("B","B","A")
classes <- rbind(classes.observation1,classes.observation2)
colnames(classes) <- c("N1.class","N2.class","N3.class")
rownames (classes) <- c("obs1","obs2")
total <- cbind(distance,classes)
df <- data.frame(total)
```

The question is: for observation j, what is the sum of the distances between N(j) and all its ith nearest neighbors that belong to Class A?

In the toy example, for the first observation, the question can be illustrated/decomposed by:

(A) what is the distance between N and its closest neighbor that belongs to Class A 
(B) what is the distance between N and its second-closest neighbor that belongs to Class A 
(C) what is the distance between N and its third closest neighbor that belongs to Class A 
(D) is A, the sum of the distance between N and the first neighbor 
(E) is (A)+(B), the sum of the distance between N  and its first neighbor, and the distance between N and its second nearest neighbor...

By chance, does anyone has a suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 0):

...getting dressed for the Piece of Junk code Award....

```
colnumber <- ncol(df)
rownumber <- nrow(df)
number.of.points <- colnumber /2

# convert Ndist to numeric
df [,1:number.of.points] <- sapply (df [,1:number.of.points], as.numeric)


# replace by 0 if class B
for (j in 1:rownumber)
    {
     for ( i in 1:number.of.points) 
       {
          if (df [j,i+number.of.points] =="B") { df [j,i] <- 0 } 
          else { df [j,i] <- df [j,i] }
       }
    }

# Sums for Class A
my.sum.for.A <- matrix(nrow =rownumber, ncol= number.of.points)
for (l in 1:rownumber) 
    {
     for ( k in 1:number.of.points) 
     { my.sum.for.A [l,k] <- sum( df [l,1:k]) }
  
    }
```

Please feel free to comment and improve...